# How to write it better way?

Tags: ruby, range

What's better and right way to write it in ruby?
I need to create something like a matrix.

```
def suggest_by_area_and_price area_range, price_range
    broker_level = case area_range
                       when 0..100
                           return case price_range
                                      when 0..25000
                                          :intern_broker
                                      when 25001..Float::INFINITY
                                          :junior_broker
                                  end
                       when 101..200
                           return case price_range
                                      when 0..18000
                                          :intern_broker
                                      when 18001..30000
                                          :junior_broker
                                      when 30000..Float::INFINITY
                                          :broker
                                  end



                       #....


                       when 1500..Float::INFINITY
                           :senior_broker
                       else
                           :junior_broker
                   end
end
```

Comment: It seems like a bad idea to keep these ranges hardcoded, to begin with. IMO they belong either to some configuration file, or to some data store.

Comment: Yep, I understand, here its for showing the thing.

Answer (score 0):

```
map = {
  (1..5) => {
    (100..200) => :foo,
    (201..300) => :bar
  },
  (6..10) => {
    (100..200) => :baz,
    (201..300) => :boo
  }
}
map.find{|k,_| k === 3}.last.find{|k,_| k === 250}.last
# => :bar
```

But, as I said in the comment, I would put this map elsewhere.